# Block offline users

Tags: controls, product-design

First I want to apology if this question doesn't fit to this forum.

Now, I have a customer who request for system that can be sell for different users.
once the user buy the system he can use it offline.

Now his business model is to have a monthly payment for the system.

Now my question is: what alternatives can we offer him to control offline users, and to suspend their account in case they don't pay.

My current suggestion is to develop the system in a way that required monthly password which generated automatically based on some pre-defined encryption key. I know it is not bullet-proof but I don't have any other approaches.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance, and sorry again if this question isn't fit to this forum.

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifying the system and its ecosystem at all, so it's tough to come up with something that might work. Dunno, what you can publish and what not, but this is what would help:

- **what the system is for** (what competition is doing, are there online solutions that might your system look outdated etc.)
- and **what kind of users** will handle the password updates (will they be ok, doing it monthly, are you giving enough value that overweights this disadvantage?)
- **how many installations** they'll have one, or they'll "need a dedicated person to do the lincese updates"?
  ...

Some "suggestions" that might or might not be helpful depending on the ecosystem. They are not something else than the code entering as I can't recall I would do anything else with offline systems, but rather hints to come up with methods how to soften and workaround its edges:

- Can you offer clustered payments and sell for a 3,6,12 months as well?
- Do you need income coming that month? Can you offer using system first and pay later, let's say to some group of users (large users, random...)?
- Do you need to be really strict and block the functionality, once user didn't paid (entered code) in time?
- Do you need all the income? Can you offer some kind of lotery of codes when from time to time you "win a free month"?
- Is the system somehow specific that it could offer really easy entering of the renewal code or at least entering it once for all installations?

*I am thinking about how things were done in old days of offline world. Any good ideas you could steal from banking systems, paper books for accounting, how railway and airplanes worked and connect them with today's options?*

Crossed fingers!

Answer (score 1):

Any security you put on the offline version can be reverse engineered by some clever person. If you provide software for non-technical business users, and have no competition, then you will probably get away with using annoying (to the users) solutions to offline licencing.

Be careful that you don't make the paid version so annoying that it is actually *easier* to use a cracked version of the software. This kind of thing happened with early DRM software, and it means you will lose money from the people who would have otherwise paid.

Remember that many people who crack DRM / security were *never* going to pay money for the product. If it wasn't crackable they just would use something else / or do without.